# ASP.NET Core storing image to SQL Server null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am a beginner in ASP.NET Core 3.1 and i am creating this application with EF Core tutorial from Microsoft site, when i try to create a new Job and store Photo, Photo attribute says null on database, i don't know why?
I used debugger to see if image is coming to Create method in controller and IFormFile Image parameter says it is null.

Model:

```
        public int JobID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("Title")]
        [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Photo")]
        public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("CategoryID")]
        [Display(Name = "CategoryID")]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [Column("CompanyID")]
        [Display(Name = "CompanyID")]
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }

        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; }
```

View - Create.html:

```
<form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Photo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="file" name="Photo" class="form-control" />
                @*<span asp-validation-for="Photo" class="text-danger"></span>*@
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Date" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CategoryID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CategoryID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CategoryID"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CompanyID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CompanyID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CompanyID"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Controller method JobsController:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("JobID,Title,Photo,Date,CategoryID,CompanyID")] Job job, IFormFile Image)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Image != null) {
            if (Image.Length > 0) {
                byte[] p1 = null;
                using (var fs1 = Image.OpenReadStream())
                using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    fs1.CopyTo(ms1);
                    p1 = ms1.ToArray();
                }
                job.Photo = p1;
            }
        }
        _context.Add(job);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    ViewData["CategoryID"] = new SelectList(_context.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryID", job.CategoryID);
    ViewData["CompanyID"] = new SelectList(_context.Companies, "CompanyID", "Name", job.CompanyID);
    return View(job);
}
```

This is where it says null: **IFormFile Image null, Job Photo attribute also null**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("JobID,Title,Photo,Date,CategoryID,CompanyID")] Job job, IFormFile Image)
```

Other attributes are stored fine, i tried almost all similar solutions but none of them helped me. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
     var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files["Photo"];
     if (file!=null && file.Length > 0)
       {
           using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
           {
                file.CopyTo(ms);
                var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                // store your bytes in db ...    
           }
       }
```

Comment: Now is working :) don't know why my code did not work, any explanation?